# Do I have to wrap a function with goroutine to use timeout?

Tags: go, timeout, goroutine

So, basically, is there any difference between these 2 blocks of code?

```golang
res := make(chan error, 1)
go func() {
        res <- slowOperation()
}()
select {
    case <-time.After(deadline):
        return errors.New("deadline exceeded")
    case err := <-res:
        return err
}
```

and

```golang
res := make(chan error, 1)

select {
    case <-time.After(deadline):
        return errors.New("deadline exceeded")
    case res <- slowOperation():
        err := <-res
        return err
}
```

Is it necessary to wrap a function in goroutine, as all of the examples on the Internet show, and if so, why?